# Create a plugin, expose events

Tags: events, jquery-plugins, plugin-architecture

How do I expose events to my plugin users?

---

I know that I should use:

```
$('#myPluginDiv').trigger('eventName', ["foo", "bar"]);
```

to trigger the event but I'm looking for best practices describing how to declare and invoke events in plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can inspect some of the most used plugins and make your own assumptions. We have no standards on this, just code convention.

Colorbox (source: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/jquery.colorbox.js) defines a prefix and some constants for the event names. It also have a function for triggering and running the callbacks.

jQuery UI (source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js) also have a common function on the widget class for triggering events (usage: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js), but you can see that the events are hard coded on the middle of the source, instead of constants on the top like on Colorbox.

I personally think, and do it in my own plugins, that creating constants is much better if you have a lot of events to trigger, but its not necessary if you will fire only 2 or 3 events.

A helper function is a must have and should be part of your template.

The event names I use and see around all follow the standard *CamelCase* e.g. `beforeClose`.

Some advocate the use of a prefix for events like on Colorbox's `cbox_open` or even `click.myPlugin` (see: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Conclusion: try to follow best practices and conventions for programming in general and watch for the better examples out there.

Answer (score -1):

in plugin create object litereal like

```
var plugin = {
  show:function(){
// code for show()
}


};
```

Comment: I was asking about best practices for exposing and publishing events. Your code doesn't even follow the jQuery plugin pattern.